# Class loading in WebLogic and Java

Tags: java, web, weblogic12c

I want to load a class if not already loaded by the web container (WebLogic 12C) using Java code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
static {
  Class.forName("org.what.Ever")
}
```

to load a class, making sure it's available and initialized. You don't need to care whether it's already loaded, as in this case the class comes out of the class loader cache. To make sure it doesn't happen too often, it will typically being put into the static initializer of another class.

Comment: I need to get the name of the instantiated class by the container. I am using the following piece of code instead of the above code as a replacement for 'getServlet()' :- '(XXX) Class.forName("packageName.XXX").cast(XXX.class)'

Comment: @Test If this didn't help you it might make sense to describe your problem in more detail. If it helped you might consider accepting the answer.

Comment: my problem is that I want to replace getServlet() code that is present in Struts1. We are migrating the application to Struts2, it is here that I want the replacement. I am thinking of replacing it with the code I provided. It works but my point is is it the solution for getServlet()?